# Why is American Toyota cars design different from European Toyota cars?

Tags: toyota

If compare Toyota same models from **toyota.com (US)** and **toyota-europe.com (Europe)** websites the models are a little bit different in design.

So I wonder why Toyota makes different cars of the same model because I think US versions are more beautiful than European models but for people who live in Europe it is a little bit problematic to buy a car in US and import it in Europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most manufacturers make localised modifications to comply with local regulations or simply expected model specifications.

In the Volkswagen scene there is a big market in exporting EU parts to the US in exchange from US parts shipped back to the UK.